# How to update compositor render after creating nodes in blender 2.81 with python?

Tags: python, rendering, node-editor

This question has already been asked in the past for blender 2.79 and below, but I have seen that it has not received any useful answers, so now I try to ask it for blender 2.81.

I have created nodes in `C.scene.node_tree.nodes`

So far everything is ok, the problem is that it does not update, so the render is the same without taking into account the newly created nodes, obviously use_nodes, it is set to True, so I also tried to make `C.scene.node_tree.nodes.update()`

```
for n in C.scene.node_tree.nodes:
    n.update()

C.scene.node_tree.links.update()
```

None of these yield results.
I noticed that it updates, only in case the render window is open, and we switch to a compositor window, in that case it updates, at this moment I need to find a solution, even just a trick that does this, without risk receiving contextual errors.
Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Comment: i'm stuck on this too.